# I can't modify my boolean fields?

Tags: java, swing, boolean, awt

Well the question explains it, no matter what I do I can't modify my Boolean fields. The following code is a class from an assignment I'm doing but I need to be able to modify Boolean values in order to do it which I can't for some reason so I'm not really sure what's going on:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Shape;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")

    public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private String senderName,reciverName,message;
    private int w=250,velx=13,x=330,senderW=350,senderH=100,reciverW=350,reciverH=270,messageW=350,messageH=50;
    private Timer tm = new Timer(50, this);
    private boolean something=true;

    public void setSomething(boolean s){            
        something=s;
    }

    public Test(String s1,String s2, String s3){
             String cutString1 = s1.substring(0, Math.min(15, s1.length()));
             String cutString2 = s2.substring(0, Math.min(15, s2.length()));
             String cutString3 = s3.substring(0, Math.min(30, s3.length()));

             senderName=cutString1;
             reciverName=cutString2;
             message=cutString3;                 
             setSomething(false);
             //Even though I set it to false it still holds true and won't print it out
           if(something=false){                
               System.out.print("Something");                  
           }                 
           setLayout(null);                
             timer();
    }

    public void timer(){            
         tm.setInitialDelay(10000);
         tm.start();        
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         setOpaque(true);            
         super.paintComponent(g);
         Font font1 = new Font(  "TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 17);
         Font font2 = new Font(  "TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30);           
         g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         g.fillRect(330, 30, 250, 390);
         g.setFont(font1);
         g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         g.drawString(message, messageW, messageH);
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.fillRect(x, 30, w, 390);
         g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         g.setFont(font2);
         g.drawString(senderName, senderW, senderH);
         g.drawString("To",430, 200);
         g.drawString(reciverName, reciverW, reciverH);
        }

    public void anime(){            
        w=w-velx;
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){                
                anime();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.add(new Test("something","something","something"));
        frame2.setTitle("Title");  
        frame2.setSize(700,500);
        frame2.setResizable(true);
        frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame2.setVisible(true);            
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of unnecessary and completely unrelated code in your question, for instance all the Swing code which has nothing to do with your problem. It really could have and should have been asked with at most 10 lines of compilable and runnable code. In the future, please have pity on the volunteers here and try to make it easier to go through and understand your code and then answer your question. For more on this, please look at: [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try `if(!something)` or `if(something == false)` == is comparison while = is assignment ! is equivalent to not. So !true would be (not true) so false. In your `if(something = false)` you are actually setting or assigning false to something so after that statement something will be false and the if will never be executed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I gave all my code because the problem may of had something to do with something else not related to the Boolean, I'm trying to give as much information as possible like some other people have mentioned.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that before coming here, you whittle down your code to try to isolate your error. This certainly is not asking too much effort since you're asking effort from volunteers. Other points for newbie questioners: focus on correct code formatting since this will also make your code easier to read and understand. Your current formatting is a bit off with excess blank lines and with non-regular indentation. Your efforts in this regard will be most appreciated.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, one question though, so in this case I should of provided my full code(my Test class which I have above) along with the Isolated error?

Comment: It's usually best to provide the smallest compilable and runnable example program that shows us your problem. This is usually a new program created, one based on your problem code, but smaller than that code base and one that is created just for posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youre using an assignment to check the variable `something` which will always be `false` so your `print` statement will never be reached:

```
if (something = false) {
```

Using the short form of the boolean check avoids this type of error:

```
if (!something) {
```

Comment: it should be `if(!something) {`

Comment: 1+ or better `if (!something)`

Answer (score 2):

> An if statement consists of a Boolean expression followed by one or
>   more statements.

Change this

```
if(something=false){

           System.out.print("Something");

       }
```

with

```
if(!something){ // for false check  }
```

or

```
if(something) //  for true check
```

**Example Why if(boolean=boolean) is not a compile time Error**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean test = true;
    int a = 0;
    boolean test1 = false;
    test1 = (test = true); // no error boolean expression
    test = (a = 1); // compile error not a boolean expression
    if(test = false)
    {

    }
    System.out.println("" + test);
}
```

Comment: Yes , it does but finally it should return a boolean value  that is why added quote after that to explain more clearly

Comment: Same here comment upvoted :) , but i have a doubt `int a=10;` `if(a=2){ }` gives me compile time error .

Comment: that's because `a=2` is not a boolean expression it doesn't return true or false.  `boolean b = true; if(b = false)` is a boolean expression.